# Can an Australian bank legally issue bank accounts and Visa cards without obtaining proof of identity from the person requesting the account?

Tags: fraud, australia, finance, banking, identification

This is the first time I have posted to StackExchange so please excuse me if my question is out of scope, is in the wrong place or goes into too much back story. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

### The Issue: short version

I have recently had an issue in which an unknown entity has opened bank accounts in my name and had Visa cards issued through an online only bank named uBank. This has all occurred in Australia.
The person who opened these accounts appears to not have any of my ID, but simply knows my name, address and date of birth.

As this has been a very long drawn out process, I will save some of the details for later, in the hopes that someone can offer some advice but the crux of the question is as follows.

My understanding, based on

1. uBank's own website https://cms.ubank.com.au/wp-content/uploads/australia-post-form.pdf
2. the advice of 4 different bank managers from 4 different banks
3. a lawyer from a major bank <sup>1</sup>
4. a consultant from AUSTRAC (the Australian Finance Regulator)

In order to open a bank account in Australia, you need to provide 100 points of ID as outlined by government guidelines, and this must include at least one form of photo id.

*<sup>1</sup> Note that a neighbour of mine spoke with a relative of theirs who is a lawyer for a major bank. I never spoke with this lawyer, so I only received their opinion second hand.*

### The Question(s)

Question 1:
Is my understanding of the legal requirements for opening a bank account in Australia correct, and if so where can I find this concisely in writing from an authoritative source? Ideally including what constitutes acceptable ID.

Question 2:
If this is correct and uBank allows the creation of a bank account without requiring the user to provide this identification, what can be done to stop it?

uBank have confirmed to me in an email that no photo ID was provided in setting up these fraudulent accounts, and they seem to have a very cavalier approach to the whole issue and aren't that concerned about trying to stop it. As one consultant handling my issue put it "We get this sort of fraud all the time."

---

### Additional question on specific legislation

I have tried looking through various legal docs online. AUSTRAC pointed me to the [Anti‑Money Laundering and Counter‑Terrorism Financing Act 2006](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2021C00243).
Whilst this document does have a section on "Identification Procedures" this seems (to me) to just state when identification procedures need to be used, and what the penalties are if not applied correctly, but does not indicate what identification procedure is required, or at least I couldn't find it.

uBank claims that they make/made identification checks against data held by Equifax, an online credit checking service.
Putting aside the fact that this seems illogical to me, since they would be checking that I am a real person with good credit rating, rather than checking that the scammer is me, Equifax have told me that according to their records, uBank never made any such check.
Section 35G of the above linked legislation, does seem to indicate that if uBank did perform the verification checks that they claim to have made then both uBank and Equifax have an obligation to make that available to me. Is that correct or am I reading that wrong?

---

### Clarification on what I am trying to achieve

Based on a couple of comments, I have tried to add some additional information about what I would like to achieve.

The person who opened these accounts appears to not have any of my ID, but simply knows my name, address and date of birth.

I am trying to find out if it is legal for a bank in Australia to allow someone to create a new account without the person opening the account providing proof of their identity?
Everything I have been told so far suggests that it is illegal, however this is largely anecdotal, and I would like something more concrete.

I am also trying to find out what can be done to stop this.
Identity fraud is a massive issue these days, and whilst it is difficult to stop criminals committing identity fraud, it feels like it should be a lot easier to stop corporations from circumventing laws that are put in place to prevent this type of criminal behaviour.
Yet every government agency who appear to be tasked with regulating banks, seem to have the attitude, that it's up to the bank to make sure they are doing the right thing.

---

### What I have tried so far

I have registered a complaint with uBank - This has received a poor response with vague assurances that the issue is resolved, but does not address the core issue at hand, which is that they continue to issue accounts without adequate checks. I also have an assurance in writing from them that the accounts had been closed and a block placed on any accounts being opened in my name. I then received a later written confirmation of this stating that the accounts were closed on a date that was a week after the Fraud teams letter assured me this had already happened.

I have registered a complaint with NAB (the issuer of the cards). They have said that since I am not a NAB customer they won't help. This is despite both NAB's fraud team and a NAB bank Manager stating that they believe these cards were issued illegally.
Do NAB have obligations here as the issuer of the cards (National Australia Bank is printed on the Visa cards)?

I have registered both of the above complaints with AFCA. They have said that they cannot get involved for a month and even then they are just a facilitator to ensure that the bank's reply to my emails.

I have spoken with AUSTRAC (The Australian Finance Regulator) and they have opened an investigation, but have told me that they cannot provide me any feedback or update on their investigation.

Are there any other avenues that could be explored?

Comment: At the end you ask what avenues can be explored–what are you hoping to accomplish? Ex: recover losses, penalize uBank, etc?

Comment: indeed: what are you trying to do? has the unknown party caused harm to you?

Comment: What do you mean saying "opened bank accounts in my name"? Is it only the name that matches, or date of birth too?

Comment: @Greendrake - The person(s) who setup these accounts used my name, address and DOB.

Comment: @user253751 - In terms of harm, it's difficult to say. As far as I am aware the person(s) in question have not got access to any of my ID and have not had access to any of my money, however they have setup bank accounts in my name, for who knows what purpose. Identity fraud is a massive issue and it relies on parlaying fraudulent credentials to progressively get more and more control/access over a victim's identity.

Comment: @Michael - I am not trying to recover any losses, or even "penalise" the bank. what I  would like to do is stop the bank from allowing fraudsters to setup bank accounts in the name of any victim they choose without providing any proof of identification. So my goal is to first find out if the law already protects people from this behaviour, and if so, who should be regulating/enforcing this?